# Writing up solutions to a book in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

I'm working through a book, which has a ton of problems in it that I would like to write answers to in LaTeX. It'll be like a solution manual, essentially (but for myself, of course).

The book has numbered chapters, and there is a single sequence of problems at the end of every chapter (e.g. chapter 1 has problems 1.1 to 1.19).

I want to write up solutions to the book in the following format:

```
Chapter 1

Exercise 1.1 What is the number of vowels in the English alphabet?
Write out the alphabet and count the vowels. There will be five.

Exercise 1.2 Some problem
A brilliant answer.

Chapter 2

Exercise 1.2 etc.
```

This is basically the format used in [this pdf](http://ctrl.cinvestav.mx/~rmartinez/papaioannoua_solutions_to_atiyah.pdf), but with the questions written out beside the numbers:
[image]

How would I do this? I know very little LaTeX outside of what goes in between the `$...$` signs.

Please retag this question as appropriate; I'm not familiar with the tags used here yet.

Comment: Take a look on the `probsoln` or `exsheets` packages. Welcome to TeX.SX by the way

Comment: There's also the `answers` package (forgot to mention)

Comment: I recommend that you consider the `eqexam` package, using the `fortextbook` option.